# SimpleXMLElement cannot get the output

Tags: simplexml

Sorry for silly question, from below can anyone advise how can I get the output above? I tried echo $xml->0, but as usual, it is syntax error...

Output:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [0] => 03 04 32N 101 46 43E
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SimpleXML returns arrays of SimpleXMLElements, thus use `$xml[0]`.

Comment: I always think of an object rather than an array. Thanks so much on this.